# Get Gps Location Using Android

Tags: android

I want to get latitude and Longitude from the following Android code.

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Here i am getting `error location is null`.

Here is the code:

```
package com.p;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 public class GooglemapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
  private TextView latituteField;
        private TextView longitudeField; 
   private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;


 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
    }
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

I have added the following permisions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Provider not available

Comment: The following library takes care of all the criteria, caching and other background work: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation

Answer (score 1):

If the last known location is null, it's because the phone has no last known location. If there is no location cached, you need to request an updated location, either via network, or GPS. Note that this process can take time, so must be done asynchronously.

You need to read this document:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

I also recommend reading this:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Answer (score 1):

You haven't define a valid Criteria. Define that as follows

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);//true if required
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);//true if required
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);//search for enabled provider
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to specify from which provider you want to receive updates.

You have two options:

- GPS_PROVIDER
- NETWORK_PROVIDER

You're probably missing something like this:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Comment: i have added following code  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this); but still getting marktext Disable provider

Comment: Also try to get the coordinates on the LocationListener interface methods. Since once you create the activity, it takes a while to get a grip of the provider and provided coordinates. You might wanna go through this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: Try printing out on StatusChanged & onLocationChanged

Comment: @tim I have used NETWORK_PROVIDER but still getting error Disable provider

Answer (score 0):

1. have you switched on GPS in Settings -> Location ?
2. why do you use `(int) (location.getLatitude())` -- latitude/longitude is a `float`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to add the following permission as well, since I am pretty sure that the FINE relies on the COARSE...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```